# Angular get the data of a subcollection from CloudFirestore and show it only for documents that contains it?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called doctors. The collection have two documents: **UYykRWfzzUMrztZqvOEZ** and
**eYOBnRuqKe3rGLM1nmoC**. Only the first document has a subcollection reviews.

- [doctors collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA1GZ.png)
- [reviews subcollections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfF9H.png)

I tried in this way:

**component.html:**
`

```js
//component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  Doctors: Doctor[];
  Reviews: Review[];
 colectie: any;
  constructor(private doctorService: DoctorInfoService, private reviewService: ReviewService, private act: ActivatedRoute, private db : AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.act.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.doctorService.getDoctorList()
      .subscribe(e => {
        this.Doctors = e.map(e => {
          return {
            doctorID: e.payload.doc.id,
            ...e.payload.doc.data() as Doctor
          }
        })
      })

      this.reviewService.getReviewInfo(id)
      .subscribe(e => {
        this.Doctors = e.map(e => {
          return {
            doctorID: e.payload.doc.id,
            ...e.payload.doc.data() as Doctor
          }
        })
      })
  }
  showReviews: boolean = false;
  getDoctorReviews() {
    this.showReviews = true;
  }
  hideDoctorReviews() {
    this.showReviews = false;
  }
}


//reviewService.ts that query the DB

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReviewService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  getDoctorID(){
    this.db
    .collection('doctors')
    
  }

  getReviewInfo(id) {
    return this.db
      .collection('doctors/'+id+'reviews')
      .snapshotChanges();
  }

}
```

```html
<!--component.html -->

<body>
  <div *ngFor="let doctor of Doctors; let i = index" class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-text">{{ doctor.name }}</h5>
          <h6 class="card-text">{{ doctor.category }}</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Rating : </p>
          <button class='btn btn-primary' (click)="getDoctorReviews()">Show Reviews</button>
          <button class='btn btn-secondary' (click)="hideDoctorReviews()">Hide</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="showReviews" class="column">
      <div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div *ngFor="let review of Reviews; let i = index" class="row">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-text">{{ review.doctorName }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Rating : {{ review.rating }}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{ review.userName }}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{ review.message }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

I know that the path to the review collection is
**'doctors' + docID + 'reviews'**
but I've blocked for too many days in **showing the review subcollection only for the correspondent document that contains it**("UYykRWfzzUMrztZqvOEZ"-> the doctor James Smith).

My expected result should be this one:

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70xI0.jpg)

One of the issues is that in component.ts the line

const id = this.act.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
returns null and I didn't find a way to do it.
I tried also to send the docID from component.html to component.ts but I didn't succed here too.

Any advice or opinion is very helpful for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "many to many" model is not ideal for Firestore reads as Firestore doesn't fetch the sub-collections for each document. If your goal is to simply render all reviews or limit them, it would be better to simply get all doctor's reviews with `.limit(x)` with `x` being your max documents to read.

`citiesRef.orderBy("created").limit(3);`

The key factor is that you are not impacted for reads when the sub-collection doesn't exist

Sources: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data